# Read words from a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that read words from a text file. My code works perfectly but why does it only read 1 word?

**Code:**

```
Public Function ReadFile1() As String
    Dim text = IO.File.ReadAllText("APStringFile\file.txt")
    ' Counting words
    Dim words = text.Split(" "c)
    Dim wordCount As String
    Dim Hasil As String
    Dim FileStart As Integer = 0
    Dim FileEnd As Integer = 100

    For i As Integer = FileStart To FileEnd
        wordCount = words(i)
        'Hasil = wordCount(i)
    Next i
    Return wordCount
End Function
```

I want to read words from 0 to 100. But the result only read words in 100 count like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me solve my problem?

Comment: Do you wan an array of strings? do you want to do somehting with each of the strings? Why the loop, since your array words already contains the words?

Comment: because I want read word with specific count like from 0 to 100 sir

Comment: If you just want to read the first 100 words you don´t need that loop at all. Linq is your friend: `wordCount = words.Take(FileEnd)`

Comment: every time you run `wordCount = words(i)` it overwrites the wordCount string with the current value of words(i). Try `wordCount &= " " & words(i)`, it will append the next word onto the wordCount string with a space in between. Or you could use the Linq solution that Alex B suggested.

Comment: @AlexB. got error like this sir http://prntscr.com/dbkrzd

Comment: @ADyson thanks sir your solution is work

Comment: @TempatBerbagiVideo I corrected my approach in my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify your code with LINQ´s [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Function ReadFile1(FileStart As Integer, FileEnd As Integer) As String
    Dim text = IO.File.ReadAllText("APStringFile\file.txt")

    ' Counting words
    Dim words = text.Split(" "c)

    'Skip the first n words then take m words
    'where n = FileStart (e.g. 0) and m = delta between FileEnd (e.g. 100) and FileStart.
    'Concat the result together to one string 
     Dim wordCount As String = String.Join(" ", words.Skip(FileStart).Take(FileEnd - FileStart).ToArray())

    Return wordCount
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReadFile1(0, 100)) 'Prints words 0 to 100
Console.WriteLine("---------")
Console.WriteLine(ReadFile1(101, 200)) 'Prints words 101 to 200
```

(I adjusted the `ReadFile1` function so it takes the `FileStart` and `FileEnd` as parameters. This makes the usage a bit more dynamic. If you don´t want/need that just remove them and add them as local variables like you had before).

**Edit**: Explicit string declaration of `wordCount` variable
**Eidt2**: Added `ToArray()` due to .NET 3.5

Comment: I use visual studio enterprise 2015 and .NET 3.5

Comment: Change `Dim wordCount as String = .....` to `Dim wordCount As String = String.Join(" ", words.Skip(FileStart).Take(FileEnd - FileStart).ToArray())`. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Introducing `Linq` is not the problem in OP case, would you explain his problem of ***why his code isn't working***? I myself didn't see in your answer of how it addressed that...

Comment: The OP´s code isn´t working because he is overwriting his wordCount variable in each loop step. This was already catched by ADyson in his comment. My code is not juist to introduce Linq. It´s less code (1 loc) and imho better understandable since `Take` and `Skip` are understandable verbs. Also my solution provides a non-hard coded way to retreive the words which will save lots of trouble for the PO in future. It would be much harder to do that without linq in terms of readability etc.

Comment: With the information I have my code also works - tested on .NET 3.5 and 4.6 with a sample text file containing some words. Without further information from the PO I can´t determine why the code is not working for him.

Comment: I try your code to show in MsgBox and not work sir ... I use code from ADyson and show in MsgBox and work ... I don't know where the error

Comment: @TempatBerbagiVideo If his code works just go for it. I don´t know why my solution fails on your system either.